# Define private / public type of struct

Tags: c#, struct

I want to define a variable that will store two parameters — username and access level. In order to do this, I choose to use the struct, that I declare in App.cs file and variable from a type of this struct that I fill-in on success authorization.

Here is some code example:

```
struct AuthSession {
    string username;
    string accessLevel;
}

public AuthSession userSession;
```

Important! The variable `userSession` must be accessible from/to all classes in order to supply the ability to check user session each time and in each place I need.

My questions:

1. Should I type `private` / `public` in the structure definition? E.g. `public struct AuthSession` vs. `struct AuthSession`.
2. If I don't type `private` / `public` in the structure definition does it set some encapsulation level by default?

Comment: Why a struct? It is **very** uncommon to declare a struct, and most times even then it is done in error. This doesn't look like a typical scenario for a valid struct...

Comment: To put that another way: if you can't state very clear reasons why it *should* be a struct, then it almost certainly shouldn't be.

Comment: @MarcGravell What's wrong with declaring a struct in C#? (I come from C++/Java background, so I don't understand)

Comment: @ScriptKitty the problem is simply that most people use them inappropriately or don't understand exactly what it means. A typical error scenario here is not making them immutable - most structs should be immutable. If people think of them as "lightweight objects", they're missing the point. Recent language changes with "readonly struct" and "ref struct" perhaps solve some of the issues, but the folks likely to know how to correctly use those language features aren't the same group that was misusing structs in the first place :)

Comment: @MarcGravell The virtue of using a `struct` over an `Object` is that objects are reference types; and sometimes those references can be `null` - which is something that should not exist. Also, structs are not reference types, so setting `customer2 = customer1` does not simply copy the reference.

Comment: @IanBoyd nullability is absolutely not a key distinguisher here, especially since a `struct` can be `Foo?` (i.e. nullable), and recent C# versions have added nullability tracking (or rather: non-nullability tracking) to reference types; a `Customer` type would *usually* (unless there are very specific needs) make an exceptionally poor `struct`; if your aim is simple shallow copies: there are good ways of doing that for reference types too - especially now we have `with`

Comment: @MarcGravell A `struct` can never be null. `Foo?` is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<T>` (which ironically is also a `struct` that can never be null). But this is needless pedantry. You wanted to know a use case for a *value-type* over a *reference-type*: a value-type can never be null. The same can **never** be said for a reference type. Ideally the C# language would change so that no reference types can **never** be null, and instead you **must** just `Nullable<T>` (and not even `?` imho). The problem being solved is that a reference types are references.

Comment: @IanBoyd yes, that is indeed needless pedantry; first, you need to define what you mean by `null`. A value-type can *absolutely* be `null`; it just can't be *a null reference* - it sounds like you're falsely equivocating "null" and "a null reference". As for "can **never** be null" (talking about references, now) - yes, it is impossible to make it 100% impossible to get a `null` reference where you shouldn't, but if you use modern C# and reference type nullability: the compiler will spot almost all reasonable scenarios for you; but: using a struct to solve this issue is **doing it wrong**; the

Comment: @IanBoyd *correct* way of handling that scenario is to *not assign nulls*; for example, you could use a field/property initializer that assigns a non-null value (perhaps a sentinel, perhaps something more useful), and then just *don't assign nulls in the future* (null-check, null-coalesce, etc; take your choice)

Comment: *"The correct way to use a value type is to use a reference type - and then use documentation, methods, error checking, and hacks to make it pretend to be a value type"* Or just use a value type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default if you don't specify a visibility modifier on a top-level class/struct it is considered `internal`. Nested class/struct default to private.

- `struct AuthSession` means internal i.e. visible only inside the assembly in which it is declared.
- `public struct AuthSession` means public i.e. accessible from other assemblies as well.

Note that this is not the same with the struct fields (`username` and `accessLevel`). If you don't specify a visibility modifier for them they are `private`.

Comment: Minor clarification: top-level types default to internal; nested types default to private

Comment: @Marc, thanks for pointing this out. It's an excellent remark and not minor :-)

Comment: In general C# defaults to the most restrictive visibility that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Are you *sure* you want a struct? If you want to store state in the struct and pass it around and populate it with values you might be surprised by the behaviour. I'd suggest using a class instead.

Consider the following example:

```
class Program
    {
        struct AuthSession
        {
            public string username;
            public string accessLevel;
        }

        class AuthSession2
        {
            public string Username { get; set; }
            public string AccessLevel { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AuthSession session = new AuthSession();
            AuthSession2 session2 = new AuthSession2();

            DoStuff(session);
            DoStuff(session2);

            Console.WriteLine(session.username + " " + session.accessLevel);
            Console.WriteLine(session2.Username + " " + session2.AccessLevel);
        }

        static void DoStuff(AuthSession session)
        {
            session.username = "a";
            session.accessLevel = "a";
        }

        static void DoStuff(AuthSession2 session)
        {
            session.Username = "a";
            session.AccessLevel = "a";
        }
    }
```

You'll note if you run this example the Main method will only have values for the class AuthSession2, *not* the struct.

Is that *really* want you want?

Comment: And what about using of static? E.g. public static AuthSession userSession = new AuthSession(); If I declare it with static it works great in any class. Should I avoid this solution because of some issues that may not be obvious to junior programer? Thanks.

Comment: Well yes.... you could do that but I still think its better to use a class here. If you're a junior programmer then I would recommend mostly avoiding using static members. They're great for small apps but as your applications grow you'll find yourself cursing them. Instance based classes are fantastic, use them and love them. :)